# Facebook login button remains the same after logging in

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I have integrated the FB login button and all works well.
It logs-in perfectly and when I go to FB I can see that the game is listed as one of the permitted apps.

However, the button shown on the screen doesn't change.
It still says "Continue with Facebook".

Isn't it meant to change to a logout button or something or am I misunderstanding something.
The documentation clearly states:`The button follows the login state, and displays the correct text based on someone's authentication state.`

This is what I added to my layout

```
    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonFaceUp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.499"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by ```integrated the FB login button```. Please provide some code.

Comment: I integrated the button as shown in the FB example. See above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the callback to your button?

```
 mLoginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                // Handle exception
            }
        });
    }
```

See the source: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/FBLoginSample/src/main/java/com/facebook/fbloginsample/FacebookLoginActivity.java

Comment: No. But I don't need it. Just want it to login - which it does